# Where is "My Computer" in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

In Ubuntu 12.10, in Nautilus, there were the following entries in the sidebar:

- "File system" - Ubuntu installation drive
- "Computer" - the equivalent of "My computer" in Windows

Now, in Ubuntu 14.04, in Nautilus, the entries have changed to:

- No "File System" entry
- "Computer" - Ubuntu installation drive

I remember giving some `computer://` command in terminal, to open equivalent of "My Computer" on Windows.

How do I open the equivalent of "My Computer" on Windows in Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: My brain just exploded reading this. Can you please post an image of what you saw on 12.04 and what you are seeing now in 14.04 for me to understand your issue.

Comment: The question title makes sense. The body is still confusing.

Comment: Looks like it's missing all the definite and indefinite articles. Bizarre.

Comment: To reviewers: this isn't about 12.10. ***Read it***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to Directly open "Computer" location, then run/type following command:

```
nautilus computer:///
```

Or by using **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>**, then type `computer:///` as follows:
[image: screen]

This will Show "Computer" which you want!

*you can also use `computer:/` only.*

Comment: Looks like any number of `/`'s works fine.

Comment: The first double slash indicates global scope, so anything following that is a system or host name. The slash following it is the beginning of the path.  If you give only two slashes, it treats it as having no path, but the default path is "/" so it'll just work the same.  If you only have one slash it'll treat the "/" as the path and not have a system name, but the default system name is empty, so it'll work the same.  And finally, if you have no slashes, it'll use the default system AND path, so it'll work the same.  So officially it's three slashes, and any less is a shortcut to the same.

Comment: Also, the ability to have *more* than three slashes is just a quirk of directory parsing where a null value as a directory name resolves to current directory, so it still just works.

Answer (score 10):

In the file manager hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> and then type in `computer://`

[image]

Note: `computer:///` also works.

Comment: compter:/ is also working.

Comment: `compter:/` does **not** work

Comment: no space in the word computer:/